# Function with constant derivative

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

We have a column matrix $P_i$ defined as follows 
 $P_i= {\begin{pmatrix}
a_i
\\
b_i 
\\ c_i
\end{pmatrix}}_{3\times 1}\tag 1 $.

**Given Data**

1. All $a_i,b_i,c_i$ are constants
2. It is given that $i$ can only take four values such that $i=0,1,2,3$. Means we are considering  $P_0,P_1,P_2,P_3$ only.$P_i$s must be unique
3. s is not matrix(mentioned below). $s\in[0,3]$. Means is a parameter which can take values from $0$ to $3$

**Question**

Can we make a function ${Q(s)}_{3\times1}=f(s,P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4),\tag 2$

such that $\frac{\mathrm{d} Q(s) }{\mathrm{d} s} $ is a constant column matrix  and satisfying the following condition

1. $Q(0)=P_0 ,Q(1)=P_1 ,Q(2)=P_2 ,Q(3)=P_3 ,$

NB:: There are no other constraints  on $Q(s)$ . All constraints are already mentioned in question and data section above. Thanks for reading this question

Comment: You must have $Q(s) = Q(0)+ s d$  (where $d ={ \partial Q(S) \over \partial s}$). This implies $P_1=P_0+d$, etc., which places constraints on the $P_k$.

Comment: But any hint on finding that Q?Can be solve that ODE?

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something, but if I understand your question correctly, you must have $Q(s) = P_0 + s(P_1-P_0)$. And hence $P_1-P_0 = P_2=P_1 = P_3-P_2$.

Comment: Then If I put $Q(3)$ how can we make sure that we get $P_3$ as per the question. $P_i$s must be unique

Comment: $P_i$s cant repeat .. I forgot to mention that.. Now just added

Comment: Sorry, I meant $P_1-P_0 = P_2-P_1 = P_3-P_2$. If $Q$ has a constant derivative and $Q(k)$ has the above values, then the $P_k$ must lie on a line (and more).